# How to implement a pseudo random function

Tags: algorithm, random

I want to generate a sequence of random numbers that will be used to pick tiles for a "maze".  Each maze will have an id and I want to use that id as a seed to a pseudo random function. That way I can generate the same maze over and over given it's maze id. Preferably I do not want to use a built in pseudo random function in a language since I do not have control over the algorithm and it could change from platform to platform. As such, I would like to know:

- How should I go about implementing my own pseudo random function?
- Is it even feasible to generate platform independent pseudo random numbers?

Comment: Look up the web! [Wikipedia:Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

Comment: Or even more [Wikipedia articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_generator) with links and references... SO is not Google, you know.

Comment: While conceptually it may be best to implement your own pseudorandom number generator, in practice it's probably best to take someone else's pseudorandom generator code that's open source and just make a copy of it for your application. That way you know it's implemented correctly and it's not going to change just because the underlying library changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160529013225/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) is an example of such an algorithm (and its use) for noise generation.

Those particular random functions (Noise1, Noise2, Noise3, ..) use input parameters and calculate the pseudo random values from there.
Their output range is from 0.0 to 1.0.

And there are many more out there (Like mentioned in the comments).

**UPDATE 2019**

Looking back at this answer, a better suited choice would be the below-mentioned `mersenne twister`. Or you could find any implementation of `xorshift`.

Comment: That link was great! Perlin noise function it is!

Answer (score 2):

The [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) may be a good pick for this.  As you can see from the pseudocode on wikipedia, you can seed the RNG with whatever you prefer to produce identical values for any instance with that seed.  In your case, the maze ID or the hash of the maze ID.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Python, you can use the random module by typing at the beginning,
import random. Then, to use it, you type-
    var = random.randint(1000, 9999)

This gives the var a 4 digit number that can be used for its id

If you are using another language, there is likely a similar module

Comment: But that doesn't solve his problem. The next release of Python might use a different random number algorithm, meaning that he'd get a different sequence of numbers for the same seed.

Comment: What he could do, though, is store a dictionary in a text file, which is added to when every new ID is created. This way, when Python does update, the new number generator would select a number, see if it is in the dictionary. If it is not, create the new maze and append to the text file with all necessary info. If the number is already used, just pick a new number, and keep checking until a number is found.

Comment: it might be easier to just seed the random number generator with random.seed(maze_id) but it's a platform-specific solution